# How to set focus on window on Mac using python, selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

```
if platform == "darwin": #if on OS X, requires this module: pip install pygetwindow
    import pygetwindow as gw
    titles = gw.getAllTitles()
    print(titles)
    win = gw.getWindowsWithTitle('Photoshop')
    win.activate()
```

This is the result in Terminal:

```
['SystemUIServer ', 'Control Centre ', 'Control Centre ', 'Spotlight ', 'Control Centre ', 'SystemUIServer ', 'Control Centre ', 'Window Server Menubar', 'Dock ', 'Photoshop ', 'Terminal ', 'IDLE ', 'Finder ', 'Finder ']
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/username/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/test.py", line 1237, in clicker1
    week_or_month()
  File "/Users/username/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/test.py", line 899, in week_or_month
    window_focus()
  File "/Users/username/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/test.py", line 680, in window_focus
    win = gw.getWindowsWithTitle('Photoshop')
AttributeError: module 'pygetwindow' has no attribute 'getWindowsWithTitle'
```

Is there any way to solve this and get focus on the window 'Photoshop'?
The function gw.getAllTitles() works.

I have also tried this (as described in another post) with the same result:

```
win = pyautogui.getWindowsWithTitle("Photoshop")
```

Result:

```
AttributeError: module 'pyautogui' has no attribute 'getWindowsWithTitle'
```

Answer (score 1):

You try to use AppleScript command to activate the window:

```
import subprocess
app_name = "Photoshop"
cmd = f'osascript -e \'activate application "{app_name}"\''
subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using the wrong call, try looking at the documentation at [documentation](https://pygetwindow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or following my example.

Your error:

`AttributeError: module 'pygetwindow' has no attribute 'getWindowsWithTitle'`

Try

`pygetwindow.getWindowsWithTitle('Photoshop') # I dont understand why you need to index into a "list"`

Also if that doesn't work, Id try the `gw.getAllTitles()` method.  `('', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe - pipenv  shell - python'")` instead of `(Win32Window(hWnd=131318), Win32Window(hWnd=1050492), Win32Window(hWnd=67206))`

Comment: This has the same result:     if platform == "darwin": #if on OS X, requires this module: pip install pygetwindow
        import pygetwindow
        titles = pygetwindow.getAllTitles()
        print("This is all open windows: ", titles)
        win = pygetwindow.getWindowsWithTitle('Photoshop')
        #win = gw.getWindowsWithTitle('Photoshop')
        win.activate()

Comment: Does anyone have any idea how to set window focus properly on Mac?

Comment: No clue I didn't think pygetwindow was compatible with mac.

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem to be compatible with Mac. The activate() method only pass and not doing anything from [Github Code](https://github.com/asweigart/PyGetWindow/blob/master/src/pygetwindow/_pygetwindow_macos.py).

It does not seem to be compatible with mac other than getAllTitles, getActiveWindow, and getWindowsAt methods. The rest are either temporary or incomplete. However, since it uses  Quartz, I am looking into that to check.